# EF7 migrations failed with PostgreSQL - relation does not exist

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I try to use ASP.NET 5 and EF7 on Linux (Debian x64). Earlier I use Windows with MS SQLServer Express, no I am using PostgreSQL (9.4) I set it up, add all nuget packages, so, It works. But when I try to apply migration:

`dnx ef database update`

I've got error:
`relation <tablename> does not exist`.

This is probably because It's impossible to create database entities (tables, functions) and then use them in the same multi-query command (github issue: [#1](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/852), [#2](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/641)).

Is there any way to do migration? Or maybe I can use some other databases?